# Should we still be seeing ads for the 2016 Survey?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising, survey-2016

I just saw an ad for the developer survey:
[image: Screenshot of SO question with an ad for the survey below the Featured box in the right hand column.]

When I clicked on it, it took me to the first page of the survey which appears to still be active. Should it be? I thought the window to take the survey closed already.

Comment: I reported a similar bug last year about ads for [Pi Day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253156/158100)

Comment: The sponsored ads on Facebook for the survey are still running too..

Comment: i took survey today only.

Comment: Yeah, they are still there :/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3Id.png

Comment: On Facebook they will took money ;)

Comment: Circle is not freehand, can you update?

Comment: Caching, obviously

Comment: Everything old is new again:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117797/i-just-saw-an-ad-for-the-stack-overflow-2012-user-survey-but-when-clicked-the-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The survey is hereby officially closed. You saw ads because the survey was still open. But now it is closed and you should no longer see ads. Unless, of course, caching.

Comment: What was that countdown for the survey about? I thought it was for the survey closing, was it actually just for consideration for the penny question?

Comment: @BSMP the countdown was based on the end date for the Meta event. House ads remained up for the survey thru the weekend.

Comment: So, status-bydesign?

Comment: @Braiam indeed!

Comment: The survey can still be accessed (not tried submitting anything, but I assume it'd work). Is this intentional (asking because SurveyMonkey supports closure of surveys)? Might mention that I still saw ads for the survey on Facebook as of a couple of hours ago.